# find individual input value in different four div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

if I have four div without class, id or name, and today I want to calculate individual input value,

so how can I do?

```html
<div id="showShoppingCart">
　　<div>
　　　　...
　　　　<input type="text" class="num" name="367303" maxlength="2" value="10">
　　　　<h3>total Quantity is: 10</h3>
　　　　...
　　</div>
　　<div>
　　　　...
　　　　<input type="text" class="num" name="367304" maxlength="2" value="10">
　　　　<input type="text" class="num" name="367305" maxlength="2" value="5">
　　　　<h3>total Quantity is: 15</h3>
　　　　...
　　</div>
　　<div>
　　　　...
　　　　<input type="text" class="num" name="367306" maxlength="2" value="10">
　　　　<h3>total Quantity is: 10</h3>
　　　　...
　　</div>
　　<div>
　　　　...
　　　　<input type="text" class="num" name="367307" maxlength="2" value="20">
　　　　<h3>total Quantity is: 20</h3>
　　　　...
　　</div>
</div>
```

Because my website is shopping cart page, maybe today users changes input `name = 367303` value **from 10 to 5**,

After change, JS will calculate the newest quantity and price and then show on the page.

But my JS logic is like:

```js
newTotalCount = 0;
numAry = [];

$('.num').each(function(){
　　newTotalCount += +$(this).val();
    numAry.push($(this).val());
});

var newNum = $('.num').parent().find('input').val();
console.log(newNum);
```

one is I use `$('.num').each` to calculate the input value, and array **numAry** is to store the input value, this way will calculate all input value.

Another is use `$('.num').parent().find('input').val()` to get input value, but this way will also get five different inputs' value, but actually I only want to calculate `name = 367303` value!

So, how can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Recalculate on change

```js
const cart = document.getElementById("showShoppingCart")
const inps = [...document.querySelectorAll("#showShoppingCart inps")];
cart.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const parent = tgt.closest("div")
  const total = parent.querySelector("h3 span")
  total.innerText = [...parent.querySelectorAll(".num")].map(inp => +inp.value).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
});
// initialise the totals
[...document.querySelectorAll("#showShoppingCart h3 span")].forEach(total => total.innerText = [...total.closest("div").querySelectorAll(".num")].map(inp => +inp.value).reduce((a, b) => a + b))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showShoppingCart">

  <div>
    <input type="text" class="num" name="367303" maxlength="2" value="10">
    <h3>total Quantity is: <span></span></h3>
    </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" class="num" name="367304" maxlength="2" value="10">
    <input type="text" class="num" name="367305" maxlength="2" value="5">
    <h3>total Quantity is: <span></span></h3>
    </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" class="num" name="367306" maxlength="2" value="10">
    <h3>total Quantity is: <span></span></h3>
    </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" class="num" name="367307" maxlength="2" value="20">
    <h3>total Quantity is: <span></span></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, if user change name=367304 input value from 10 to 5, I need to recalculate total quantity, old quantity is 10+5=15, new quantity us 5+5=10

Comment: I only want to calculate the changed input value which in their divs' input value, just like  I change name=367304 input value from 10 to 5, I need to recalculate total quantity, old quantity is 10+5=15, new quantity us 5+5=10

Comment: Not calculate all of the input value

Comment: I update my code, see, my mean is the name=367304 change from 10 to 5, the <h3> now will show total quantity is 10, right? I only want to calculate this.

Comment: Finally some clarity. See update

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try now!